# Using simple arguments in a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How do I check in my bash script if a certain argument was passed in a command?

I have had a hard time finding any information on this.

Example:

```
$ mycommand
This returns this message!

$ mycommand -a
Since the -a argument was passed, this message shows!
```

How would I check that? I feel like it's super easy but I can't really seem to figure it out.

Comment: `getopt` / `getopts`, `$1`, `$@`, `shift`.